# Replace several input values in same text

Tags: jquery, html, input, replace

This is another question related to my previous thread: [Replace several input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622088/replace-several-input-values)

Basically in my chat system. When the users types '*message hello!*' in the input box, only *'hello!'*  is outputed. The same goes for the *shout* command.  (see code below).

But, If the user types '*shout message hello!*' I still want both *shout* and *message* to be ignored. Which is not the case! Can anyone help me wrap this up?

```
function checkValue() {
  var value = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  // message
  if(value.indexOf("message") != -1) {
    $('#output').html(value.replace('message', ''));
  }
  // shout
  else if(value.indexOf("shout") != -1) {
    $('#output').html(value.replace('shout', ''));
  }
  else {
  // ...
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use an else.  You want all of the checks to happen, not an either or.   See my answer below.

Comment: This seems as if you're blacklisting specific words in a messaging/chat app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't bother with the `if`, and use regular expressions:

```
$('#output').html(value.replace(/shout|message/gi, ''));
```

If you have an array of words that you wish to prevent:

```
var unspeakables = ['shout', 'message', 'whatever'];
$('#output').html(value.replace(new RegExp(unspeakables.join('|'),'gi'), ''));
```

The `gi` means the regular expressions will search globally (`g`) within the string, and be case-insensitive (`i`) so it'll match `shout`, `SHOUT` and `ShoUT` (among other upper/lower case combinations).

Unfortunately the above will also match the character sequence of `shout` in `shouting` and `shouted`, if that's a bug in your use-case you can use the `\b` to signify that a word-end must be found as part of a match:

```
var unspeakables = ['shout', 'message', 'whatever'];
$('#output').html(value.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + unspeakables.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b','gi'), ''));
```

The `\b` becomes `\\b` to escape the `\` character that was itself escaping the `b` character (making it a special character, rather than a literal `b` character to be found (regular expressions are a little complicated and, frequently, appear arcane).

> I also have a follow up if you don't mind. My *shout* turns the text color "red" like so `$('#output').css("color", "red");` while my *message* doesn't. If the text contains 'shout', then the text should turn red. Else it should stay the same. I have an idea of how to proceed but don't know how to mention the 'shout'.

You can use an object, coupled with the callback function available to `replace()`:

```
var unspeakables = ['shout', 'message', 'whatever'],
    formatting = {
        'shout' : {
            'color' : 'red'
        }
    };
$('#output').html(value.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + unspeakables.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b','gi'), function(matchedWord){
    $('#output').css(formatting[matchedWord.toLowerCase()] || {});
    return '';
}));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6P82v/2/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Worked great and cut my code in half! Great answer, thank you.

Comment: I also have a follow up if you don't mind. My _shout_ turns the text color "red" like so `$('#output').css("color", "red");` while my _message_ doesn't. If the text contains 'shout', then the text should turn red. Else it should stay the same. I have an idea of how to proceed but don't know how to mention the 'shout'.

Comment: Um, I think that's addressed? It is, however, entirely untested and put together off the top of my head; so it may not work, or not quite as intended... :-/

Comment: It didn't quite seem to work. Everything is being outputed correctly but the shout text isn't turning red :(. I have the code setup here if you'd like to take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bhfrd/ 
+1 for the edit though, thank you, I see the logic behind it.

Comment: I've just fixed an (idiotic) typo in the answer; I habitually use `a` for the found word in a regex callback, here I called it `matchedWord` in the function's arguments (to be helpful with meaningful names) and then promptly forgot about that and called it `a` everywhere else >.< incidentally, iPad appears unsuited for codepen, sadly. It does work (for JS and HTML) over at JS Fiddle, though. So I could perhaps assist there.

Comment: Here yo go: http://jsfiddle.net/6P82v/1/ (I get a POST error request when using jsfiddle, so that's why I stick to codepen...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use regex for that :

```
value = value.replace(/(message|shout) +/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use if else only one condition will be run, to satisfy your scenario you need both cases to run.

```
function checkValue() {
  var value = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  // message
  if(value.indexOf("message") != -1) {
    $('#output').html(value.replace('message', ''));
  }
  // shout

  if(value.indexOf("shout") != -1) {
    $('#output').html(value.replace('shout', ''));
  }
  else {
  // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the else.   You want all the checks to happen...  not one or the other.

```
function checkValue() {
  var value = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  // message
  if(value.indexOf("message") != -1) {
    $('#output').html(value.replace('message', ''));
  }
  // shout
  if(value.indexOf("shout") != -1) {
    $('#output').html(value.replace('shout', ''));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkValue() {
  var value = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  if(value.indexOf('shout message') !== 0){
      // message
      if(value.indexOf("message") != -1) {
        $('#output').html(value.replace('message', ''));
      }
      // shout
      else if(value.indexOf("shout") != -1) {
        $('#output').html(value.replace('shout', ''));
      }
      else {
      // ...
      }
  }
}
```